# Rear blinker failure on camper trailer

Tags: electrical, ford, turn-signal, trailer, f-250

My right rear blinker on camper trailer does not work but every thing else does. I have a test light to test fuses and relays on truck to see if that may be an issue. It has camper tow package. Where do I ground the test light safely to begin checking?

The truck is a 2008 F-250 Super Duty with 6.4 liter engine.

Comment: Welcome to mechanics.se. I have submitted an edit to your question to make it clear in the title that the problem is with the turn signal on the trailer, not the truck itself, and to add some more useful tags. Also, it might help if you could edit the question to add more information about the trailer: make, model, year.

Answer (score 1):

You can ground your test light at any place where there's a good ground. That might be a bare nut/both, off the leaf springs, on a rust spot on the bumper ... anywhere.

There are two types of connectors I've seen for smaller trailers (4 way or 7 way). If you are using the 4 way, I've seen if you twist the two connectors together (work them back/forth against each other a little), it will help with making the connection. If you are using the 7 way (which I bet you are), check both the truck and trailer sides for corrosion. If neither of these pan out, check to ensure you don't have any corrosion in the bulb sockets on that side of the trailer.

You can also apply a 12v source directly to the trailer leads. This will let you know if the problem is on the truck side or on the trailer side.

Comment: Ya I'm using 7 way. Rear lamp lights are all new but I will definitely try the 12 volt battery idea that's good thinking there. Thank you